# In Sass, How do you reference the parent selector and exclude any grandparent?

Tags: sass

I have the following sass code:

```
.class{
    label{
        color:#fff;
        .disabled &{color:#333; }
    }
}
```

which outputs

```
.disabled .class label
```

Is there a way to output the parent selector without any grandparent selectors being included? Like so:

```
.disabled label
```

Answer (score 6):

There's no way I know of in SASS to pick and choose from ancestor selectors when using a parent reference. With your code, though, a little reorganization can get you the same result:

```
label {
    .class & {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .disabled & {
        color:#333;
    }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
.class label {
  color: #fff; }
.disabled label {
  color: #333; }
```

Answer (score 6):

Even though hopper is not enterly wrong, you can actually select grand-parent with variables.

You can achieve what you want with this:

```scss
.class{
    label{
        color:#fff;

        $selector: nth(&,1);
        $direct-parent: nth($selector, length($selector));

        @at-root #{$direct-parent} {
          .disabled &{color:#333; }
        };
    }
}
```

Which will generate this css:

```css
.class label {
  color: #fff;
}
.disabled label {
  color: #333;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The parent selector is always a reference to the entire resolved selector from the previous level of nesting.  There is no concept of "parent" or "grandparent", especially when concatenating selectors or using the parent selector at the end muddies the water.

**Disclaimer: I do not recommend doing this unless you *really really need to***.

Starting with Sass 3.4, you can extract portions of a selector by using `&` as a variable.  When used this way, you'll get a list of list of strings (which can be looped over, etc.).

## Extracting a part or *slice* of a selector

This function here uses the same style of arguments as the string-slice function:

```
@function selector-slice($sel, $start: 1, $end: -1) {
    $collector: ();
    @each $s in $sel {
        // calculate our true start and end indices when given negative numbers
        $_s: if($start > 0, $start, length($s) + $start + 1);
        $_e: if($end > 0, $end, length($s) + $end + 1);
        $c: ();
        @for $i from $_s through $_e {
            $c: append($c, nth($s, $i));
        }
        // prevent duplicates from creeping in
        @if not index($collector, $c) {
            $collector: append($collector, $c);
        }
    }
    @return $collector;
}

/* complex example */
.one-a, .one-b {
    two {
        three {
            color: red;

            &:before {
                @at-root #{selector-slice(&, 2, 3)} {
                    color: green;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/* your example */
.class {
    label {
        color:#fff;
        @at-root #{selector-slice(&, -1, -1)} {
            .disabled & {
                color:#333;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
/* complex example */
.one-a two three, .one-b two three {
  color: red;
}
two three:before {
  color: green;
}

/* your example */
.class label {
  color: #fff;
}
.disabled label {
  color: #333;
}
```

As an added bonus, you can use this function to reverse the order of the selectors by passing in the larger index before the smaller one.

```
.one-a, .one-b {
    two {
        three {
            color: red;

            &:before {
                @at-root #{selector-slice(&, 3, 2)} {
                    color: green;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.one-a two three, .one-b two three {
  color: red;
}
three:before two {
  color: green;
}
```

Related: [Modifying the middle of a selector in Sass (adding/removing classes, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593476/modifying-the-middle-of-a-selector-in-sass-adding-removing-classes-etc)

## Replacing one class with another

Alternately, you could just use the `selector-replace` function from the standard library if what you're looking to do is replace one class with another.

```
.class {
    label {
        color:#fff;
        @at-root #{selector-replace(&, '.class', '.disabled')} {
            color:#333;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.class label {
  color: #fff;
}
.disabled label {
  color: #333;
}
```