# Appending to class name via nesting with attribute selector

Tags: sass

I have the following sass:

```
.list {
    &__button{
        cursor:pointer;
        display: block;
        padding: 4px;
        border:1px solid $color4;
        outline: none;
        &__square {
            border: 1px solid $color1;
            width:12px;
            height:12px;
        }

        &__text {       
            padding-right: 5px;
            color: red;
        }
    }

    &__button[state-selected="true"] {
        .list__button__text {       
            color       : $color1;
        }
    }
}
```

I have to use the full name of the class to get this part to work:

```
&__button[state-selected="true"] {
    .list__button__text {       
        color       : $color1;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to simplify this part? Something like:

```
&__button[state-selected="true"] {
    &__text {       
        color       : $color1;
    }
}
```

But this gives an error: Invalid parent selector for "&__text": ".list__button[state-selected="true"]".

Comment: And what happens when you try your proposed code?  I don't see what's wrong with what you already have.

Comment: I get an error: Invalid parent selector for "&__text": ".list__button[state-selected="true"]"

Comment: Ok, so don't nest (or reduce the amount of nesting you're using)?  I don't see why there is an issue here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Appending a class to the middle of a selector in Sass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593476/appending-a-class-to-the-middle-of-a-selector-in-sass)