# When parent has class then change child style?

Tags: sass

I want to add a class to the container, and it'll also change the child style,

and here's the scss what I hoping for:

```
.container
{
  .mask
  {
    background: #FFF;

    // When parent(.container) has ".new" class then change the ".mask" background.
    // possible?
    &&.new
    {
      background: #000;
    }
  }
}
```

In pure css can do it like this:

```
.container .mask{ background: #FFF; }
.container.new .mask{ background: #000; }
```

Is this the only way I can do this?

```
.container
{
  .mask      { background: #FFF; }
  &.new .mask{ background: #000; }
}
```

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593476/appending-a-class-to-the-middle-of-a-selector-in-sass

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Sass doesn't offer a solution out of the box, but here's a DIY one.

```
=context($context, $addition)
  @at-root #{selector-replace(&, $context, $context + $addition)}
    @content

.container
  $parent: &
  .mask
    background: #FFF
    +context($parent, '.new')
      background: #000
```

You need to set the `$parent` variable at any depth in the nested structure that you want to refer to and modify later, because this can change depending on the situation.

I moved the logic to a mixin so it's as clean as possible. It's still a bit verbose, but it does the job without any unnecessary repetition.

Comment: This was a good answer. Using this. Not sure why was this down-voted. By the way, if there is a better solution, then I would like to see it.

Answer (score -1):

In sass you can write like this:

```
.container
  .mask
    background: #FFF
  &.new
    .mask
      background: #000 !important
```

**EDIT**

As per your comment, you can do this:

```
.container
  .mask
    background: #FFF
.new
  .mask
    background: #000 !important
```

Comment: Ummm, I hoping I can write that in ".mask", not still in ".container"..

Comment: Really sorry about my grammer, I mean I want to know ".container" has ".new" class or not in ".mask" class, so maybe I need to get parent's parent(?) in ".mask" something like this, just like my first code, really sorry ._.

Comment: @YamiOdymel The above SASS should also work as **background: #000** will only get applied if **container** has another class **new**