# Is there a more concise way to write this SASS?

Tags: sass

```
.dark {
    .header {
        background: red;
    }
    .week .header {
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

I was hoping something like this:

```
.dark {
    .header {
        background: red;
        .week &^ {
            background: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

where `$^` would only pull in the most recent parent. I tried playing with `@at-root` and `#{}`, but I couldn't figure anything out.

Comment: I thought just `&` was the parent: [Referencing parent selectors using the ampersand character](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand). Btw, it seem you have SCSS, not SASS.

Comment: @GolezTrol: The terms parent and child are basically meaningless these days. Hardly anybody ever uses them correctly. And although the syntax is SCSS, the preprocessor is still called Sass.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28593476/2065702