# SASS - Modify class pseudo

Tags: css, sass, gulp-sass

To be honest, my title for this question is really not very descriptive. It's so hard to put into words what I need to do, but I think it's a pretty common use-case, so maybe code is the best way to describe.

**What I need to generate**

```
.little-tag:before {
  content: "Generic text";
  /** lots more stuff to setup the little tag **/
}

.special.little-tag:before {
  content: "Special text";
}

.extra-special.little-tag:before {
  content: "Extra special text";
}
```

**What I tried**

```
.little-tag:before {
  content: "Generic text";
  /** lots more stuff to setup the little tag **/

  &.special {
    content: "Special text";
  }

  &.extra-special {
    content: "Extra special text";
  }
}
```

**What actually gets produced**

```
.little-tag:before {
  content: "Generic text";
  /** lots more stuff to setup the little tag **/
}

.little-tag:before.special {
  content: "Special text";
}

.little-tag:before.extra-special {
  content: "Extra special text";
}
```

I'm compiling using `gulp-sass`.

In short, I'm creating a pseudo selector that puts a tag (not `HTML`, but literally a visual tag) into all elements that have a class of `little-tag`. In SOME circumstances the contents of this visual tag needs to change depending on another class that the target element has. So the visual tag will say *Generic text* for most, but some will say *Special text* and some others will say *Extra special text*.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593476/modifying-the-middle-of-a-selector-in-sass-adding-removing-classes-etc

Comment: @cimmanon `@at-root .special#{&}` did the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve your intended results:

```
.little-tag {
  &:before {
    content: "Generic text";
    /** lots more stuff to setup the little tag **/
  }

  &.special:before {
    content: "Special text";
  }

  &.extra-special:before {
    content: "Extra special text";
  }
}
```