# Is it possible to concatenate two siblings without parent in Sass?

Tags: sass, siblings

What I want is concatenate two child inside the parent but without choosing the parent on output.

What I mean is here:

```
.parent {
  .child {
    color: green;
    & + & {
      margin-top: 6px;
    }
  }
}
```

On the output I have this:

`.canvas-btn .canvas-btn__icon + .canvas-btn .canvas-btn__icon {margin-top: 6px;}`

but if it's possible to make the next way without duplicating the code is Sass?

`.canvas-btn .canvas-btn__icon + .canvas-btn__icon {margin-top: 6px;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the parent selector (`&`) as a variable here and treat it like the list of lists that it is:

```
@function nest-adjacent-selector($sel) {
    $new-sel: ();
    @each $s in $sel {
        $last: nth($s, -1);
        $new-sel: append($new-sel, $s #{'+'} $last, comma);
    }
    @return $new-sel;
}

.parent {
    .brother, .sister {
        color: green;
        @at-root #{nest-adjacent-selector(&)} {
            margin-top: 6px;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.parent .brother, .parent .sister {
  color: green;
}
.parent .brother + .brother, .parent .sister + .sister {
  margin-top: 6px;
}
```

Note that this will not work if you're using [certain versions of LibSass](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/1796).  For more information on how this works, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593476/modifying-the-middle-of-a-selector-in-sass-adding-removing-classes-etc).